# Introducir un documento Word dentro de otro documento Word conservando su formato

Tags: python-3.x, docx

como puedo introducir un documento.docx dentro de otro documento Word (Original.docx) pero conservando todo su formato (negrita, tabulaciones, etc...)

```
doc = Document('Original.docx')
doc2 = Document('documento.docx')
```

Ya lo he podido ingresar pero siempre pierde su formato (negrita, tabulaciones, fuente, etc...)

No he encontrado mucha información.... alguien sabe como podría insertar el documento.docx sin perder su formato. Gracias

Comment: Buenos días entiendo, creí que sí lo había etiquetado

Answer (score 0):

El título de la pregunta habla sobre "introducir un documento word dentro de otro", pero ese tipo de "anidamiento de documentos" no tiene demasiado sentido. Supongo que lo que quieres es **añadir** el contenido de un documento al final de otro.

También supongo (por las etiquetas de la pregunta) que quieres hacerlo con Python3 y usando la biblioteca `docx`.

Lo primero decir que no hay forma sencilla de "juntar" dos documentos Word debido a que cada documento puede definir sus propios estilos, y en ese caso ¿cuál sería el estilo "ganador"? Es decir, imagina que un documento usa un formato para estilo "Titulo 1", mientras que el otro usa un estilo completamente diferente. ¿Con cuál de los dos te quedarías? Otro caso difícil: cada documento define sus propios "estilos de usuario" ¿cómo mezclarlos?

Si dejamos de lado los problemas de estilos y suponemos que ambos formatos usan los estilos por defecto, y nos centramos tan sólo en añadir contenido de un documento a otro, podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
doc = Document('Original.docx')
doc2 = Document('documento.docx')

for paragraph in doc2.paragraphs:
    text = paragraph.text
    doc.add_paragraph(text)
```

Pero esto no preservará el formato, sólo el texto.

Otro posible enfoque que no he podido probar pero que en teoría sí te permitiría mantener formato podría ser:

```
doc = Document('Original.docx')
doc2 = Document('documento.docx')

doc.add_page_break()  # Si quieres que el documento añadido empieze en pág nueva
for element in doc2.element.body:
    doc.element.body.append(element)
```

Comment: justamente eso quise preguntar... muchas gracias, tampoco he encontrado mucha información al respecto... trataré de solucionarlo desde otro enfoque.

Comment: ¿Y no te sirven los que te he propuesto? ¿Por qué?